# String concatenation in value bind in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have just started learning `Vue`, so it might be silly question.
I have created a Vue component and want to do string concatenation in value bind.

Like this.

```
Vue.component('button-counter',{
    data:function(){
        return { count : 0}
    },
    template:"<input type='button' v-on:click='count++' v-bind:value='"Total Counter :"+count'/>"
})
```

But it's seems to be wrong syntax. Can anyone please help me on how I can achieve this.

In example there is another way of doing this, e.g:

```
template: '<button v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})
```

But is it possible to achieve using value binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a computed property. I would also probably swap this up from an input type to a button, but here is how to solve with current input.

```js
new Vue(({
  el: "#app",
  data:function(){
    return { count : 0}
  },
  computed: {
    buttonText() {
      return "Total Counter : " + this.count; 
    }
  }, 
  template:"<input type='button' v-on:click='count++' v-bind:value='buttonText'/>"
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>
<html>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: why computed property?

Comment: Stylistic, either is fine, i prefer to keep my text together like this as a single concept, future me prefers to grok "buttonText" instead of parsing the button html to see that it is some variable text.

Answer (score 6):

As has already been noted in another answer you could use a computed property to remove the expression entirely but that is not required to get your code to work. If you had been using a single file component then your template would have worked fine. The 'wrong syntax' here is a consequence of using a double-quoted string literal for your template, leading to nested double quotes.

The double quotes need escaping with slashes. This is nothing to do with Vue, it's raw JavaScript:

```
template:"<input type='button' v-on:click='count++' v-bind:value='\"Total Counter :\"+count'/>"
```

While not incorrect, I would also suggest abbreviating `v-on:click` to `@click` and `v-bind:value` to `:value`.

```
template: "<input type='button' @click='count++' :value='\"Total Counter :\" + count'/>"
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to escape the double quotes, this is because your template is surrounded by them.

```
    template:"<input type='button' v-on:click='count++' v-bind:value='\"Total Counter :\"+count'/>"
```

if it was in a template like this you don't have to escape.

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <input type='button' v-on:click='count++' v-bind:value="'Total Counter :'+count"/>
      </div>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good this works for me

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type='button' v-on:click='count++' v-bind:value="'Total Counter :'+count"/>
  </div>
</template>
```